# testNG test invocation exception

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

*When I try to run my TestNG test , I get the below exception . I tried ..project clean and then mvn eclipse:clean , mvn eclipse:eclipse in that order ..also have tried mvn clean install after that ..This error just wont go away . There was no issues in the test and was running fine before I made some changes

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.<class Name>
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:331)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:295)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:183)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:416)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:242)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:166)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:143)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:272)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MapLookup.newMap(I)Ljava/util/HashMap;
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MainMapLookup.<clinit>(MainMapLookup.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:53)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:337)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:150)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:358)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:416)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:473)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:418)
    at com.intuit.cg.qa.tto.test.BaseTest.<init>(BaseTest.java:47)
    at com.intuit.cg.qa.tto.test.fed.productupsell.ProductUpsellBaseTest.<init>(ProductUpsellBaseTest.java:40)
    at com.intuit.cg.qa.tto.test.fed.monetization.Monetization.<init>(Monetization.java:57)
    ... 26 more
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.BaseMessageSender$ReaderThread.run(BaseMessageSender.java:254)
```

Comment: By the look of your exception you have an incompatibility of your LOG4J dependencies. `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MapLookup.newMap(I)Ljava/util/HashMap;`

Comment: Thank you for the response ..this test is running fine from command line where there is no log4j dependency error..Its just from eclipse this is acting weird .

Comment: Then configure your eclipse to use the external maven instead of the embedded one.